# Set column titles in QColumnView

Tags: qt, pyqt

Is there an easy way to add column titles to each column? I googled around, found some small hints[1] but not a working example. I use PyQT but other examples may be portable. Thanks.

Edit:
I use a custom model class that extends QAbstractItemModel, so I can't use anything on QStandardItem.

[1] Mentioned example is missing: http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_can_i_set_headers_for_a_qcolumnview

Comment: Please show your code  instead.

Comment: It's in 'Model' class, not 'View' class. You mean having separate 'Model' class is "not easy"?

Comment: Yeah, Sorry, I forgot to mention that I use a custom model class.

Answer (score 0):

in c++ it is:

```
QStringList columnTitles = QStringList() << "a" << "b" << "c";
for (int i = 0; i < columnTitles.count(); ++i)
    model->setHeaderData(i, Qt::Horizontal, columnTitles.at(i), Qt::DisplayRole);
```

so python could be (possibly wrong):

```
columnTitles = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i in range(len(columnTitles)):
    model.setHeaderData(i, Qt.Horizontal, columnTitles[i], Qt.DisplayRole)
```

cheers zai

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I use a custom model class, so, there's nothing from QStandardItemModel available

Comment: is it at least derived from `QAbstractItemModel`?

Comment: Not really, the code doesn't throw an error but every call to setHeaderData() returns false and no header is displayed.

Comment: then i am out of ideas; it might help to see some of the code

Answer (score 0):

You can override virtual `headerData()` in your custom model class to return the desired values.

Comment: I already tried that with an empty method to check whether it gets called from the view. Don't know why, but the method isn't invoked at all.

Comment: @PeterClause May be `columnCount()` returns 0? Check debug messages. Something is wrong.

Comment: Nope, columnCount() always returns 1.

Comment: @PeterClause What classes are model/view derived from?